# PostgreSQL: How to create a foreign key on a table with inheritance

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to create the following tables structure:

```
create table base_auditoria (
    ip_usuario_aud      character varying(30)           not null,
    id_usuarioa_aud     integer                         not null
);

create table pessoa (
    id        serial               not null,
    nome      character varying    not null,
    constraint pk__pessoa__id primary key (id)
) 
inherits (base_auditoria);

create table pessoa_fisica (
    cpf       character varying(11)     not null,
    nome_mae  character varying         not null
)
inherits (pessoa);

create table usuario (
    id                      serial                          not null,
    id_pessoa               integer                         not null,
    email                   character varying(500)          not null,
    constraint pk_usuario_id primary key (id)   
)
inherits (base_auditoria);
```

After creating them, insert only one record in the table "usuario" and only one record in the table "pessoa_fisica":

```
INSERT INTO pessoa_fisica (cpf, nome_mae, nome, ip_usuario_aud, id_usuario_aud) 
    VALUES ('cpf 001', 'nome mae 001', 'pessoa.nome 001', '255.255.255.255', 0);

INSERT INTO usuario (id_pessoa, email, ip_usuario_aud, id_usuario_aud)
    VALUES ( 
        (SELECT id FROM pessoa_fisica WHERE cpf = 'cpf 001' LIMIT 1),
        'test@test', '0.0.0.0', 0
    );
```

So I update the two records to contain the correct identifiers that are foreign keys:

```
UPDATE usuario SET id_usuario_aud = id; 
UPDATE pessoa_fisica SET id_usuario_aud = (SELECT id FROM usuario LIMIT 1);
```

When I run the SELECT, I get the expected answers:

```
db=# SELECT * FROM usuario;

 ip_usuario_aud | id_usuario_aud | id | id_pessoa |   email   
----------------+----------------+----+-----------+-----------
 0.0.0.0        |              1 |  1 |         1 | test@test
(1 registro)


db=# SELECT * FROM pessoa_fisica

 ip_usuario_aud  | id_usuario_aud | id |      nome       |   cpf   |   nome_mae   
-----------------+----------------+----+-----------------+---------+--------------
 255.255.255.255 |              1 |  1 | pessoa.nome 001 | cpf 001 | nome mae 001
(1 registro)


ab=# SELECT * FROM pessoa;

 ip_usuario_aud  | id_usuario_aud | id |      nome       
-----------------+----------------+----+-----------------
 255.255.255.255 |              1 |  1 | pessoa.nome 001
(1 registro)


ab=# SELECT * FROM ONLY pessoa;

 ip_usuario_aud | id_usuario_aud | id | nome 
----------------+----------------+----+------
(0 registro)
```

When I try to add a FOREIGN KEY constraint with the following command, I get the error:

```
alter table usuario 
    add constraint fk_1 
    foreign key (id_pessoa) 
    references pessoa (id) 
    match simple on update no action on delete no action;
```

> **ERROR:** insert or update on table "usuario" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk_1" DETAIL: Key (id_pessoa) = (1) is not present in the table
>   "pessoa".

**How can I solve this problem?**

**Solution 1:** Remove inheritance and work with foreign key relationships only;

**Solution 2:** Create a trigger to copy the table data "pessoa_fisica" to "pessoa" with the command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_tg_1() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        IF tg_op = 'INSERT' THEN  
            INSERT INTO pessoa 
                SELECT ip_usuario_aud, id_usuario_aud, id, nome 
                FROM pessoa_fisica 
                WHERE id = new.id;      
        ELSIF tg_op = 'UPDATE' THEN 
            UPDATE pessoa SET 
                ip_usuario_aud = new.ip_usuario_aud, 
                id_usuario_aud = new.id_usuario_aud, 
                nome = new.nome 
                WHERE id = new.id;
        ELSIF tg_op = 'DELETE' THEN
            DELETE FROM pessoa WHERE id = new.id;
        END IF;
    END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_1 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON pessoa_fisica FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_tg_1();
```

Thus the foreign key "fk_1" can be created.

**Is there any other alternative?**

Comment: the only solution i found was: create a datamodel without inheritence

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS

Comment: Probably I'll stop using inheritance if they do not get a satisfactory solution.

Comment: The solution "2" implies data duplication.

Comment: Basically you can't. For this to work PostgreSQL would need to support unique indexes spanning multiple relations, and it doesn't yet.